# In resource allocation, how do you call the group of people that will be hired in the future?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, project-management-style, resources

In other words, in my "MS Project-like tool", I have teams with the people that I've already hired, and unassigned people mark as in the "bench" team.

I'm looking for a placeholder team name to put the future hires of this quarter, to plan possible project assignments for them.

I'm confused about what would be the best name for this (it's not "bench" because I don't want to mix them with the already hired people with no current project assignment).

EDIT: I'm using float.com, and I'm using the "department" for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you not answered your own question by referring to them as "future hires"?

Comment: yeah but I ment something like a one word concept like, I dont know, pipeline, or something. is there a concept in theory about this or should I go with future hires and that's it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term usually used is "Candidate Pool" / "Succession pool".

This usually includes candidates that you are planning to at least keep in mind in case you'll need to expand your workforce.